# Using sessions in Registry Pattern

Tags: php, class

I have a user page, where users can see and edit there profile. The application does not use ajax. The application flow is like below:

1. I have a user class which fetches all data from mysql. I use this class to display the profile of a user.
2. The object of the user class is stored in a registry class. Basically i dont want to instantiate the class again.
3. When the user clicks on edit profile button, the page refreshes and makes profile form editable. Here the registry class gets instantiated again, so the user object is lost. So again i have to call the user class to get the from mysql.

**Is it a good practice to use one the point below:**

> 1) I can store the registry class(object) in a session. So from any
>   other page, i can access this registry class from the session.
>
> 2) The objects which are getting registered in the registry, should
>   get stored in a session. So from any page, i will initialize the
>   registry class and from there if i call the user class, it will first
>   check in the session. If the object is found in session, good or else
>   it will create the object.

I have seen few Registry classes, but they have not implemented any kind of session inside it.

Basically my application is much bigger than this, so i just wrote a small scenario above.

Answer (score 0):

If your object are huge i would store whole object in session, if not - then only data.

I dont know exactly what you have (as you told - its only a small piece so we can advice you).

But storing whole huge object and then just taking it is faster (as its serialized) than storin its all data in session and then reinitializing the object from scratch.